# Unexpected token ILLEGAL (ELF) Raspberry Pi Node Webkit Linux v0.31.3

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, nwjs

I downloaded the sdk executable from dl.nwjs.io/v031.3, tried 32 and 64 bit version for Linux.

I try to run these on a raspberry pi 3b+,  with
node Desktop/nwjs-sdk-v0.31.3-linux-x64/nw

get this error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ?ELF???

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
 at new Script 
....... at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:240:19)
```

Note I am running the code straight from nwjs.io, not copying any whitespace characters in from stackoverflow or other sources like somerelated questions suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is because you are trying to run NW.js compiled for x86 (and x64) platforms but Raspberry Pi uses ARM architecture.

You can find a NW.js binary that will work in all Raspberry Pi versions out of the box here: https://github.com/jalbam/nwjs_rpi